# a or the before "better"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I am bit confused on what to put - 'a' or 'the' before "better"

for example

- better life
- better job
- better work

Comment: It depends on whether the context is a simple comparison or something closer to Kant's categorical imperative.

Comment: Context is simple. For example, a book or note title

Comment: Adjectives do not affect the correct article that depends on your intended meaning.

Comment: @ I-M-JM The whole purpose of the determinatives "the and "a" is to mark a noun phrase as definite or indefinite. If I use a definite NP to say _I want **the better job**_, I'm assuming you know which job I'm referring to. But there's no such assumption made with an indefinite NP, as in _I want **a better job**_.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about the definite and indefinite articles in general, have a look at [these questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=definite%20indefinite%20article) on ELU and [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/19744/question-about-articles) on ELL.

For *better*, there is another consideration that depends on the context of the situation. That is, it depends on the way in which you consider that life, job or work to be *better*.

For example, if Company A offers you a job that is more enjoyable and pays more than Company B, you are faced with a simple comparison. You might say:

> Company A is offering **a better job** than Company B.

If Company A paid less than Company B, it's still a simple comparison (English-wise, anyway), and you can use the same sentence if you preferred Company A overall.

On the other hand, if you are contrasting an honest profession with a disreputable one, you're invoking something like [Kant's categorical imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_imperative). There's really only one choice that can even be considered *good*. In that case, you would use 'the'. For example:

> Honest living may not pay as well as criminal activity, but it is **the better life**.

Comment: I think it's important to bring out the indefinite vs definite contrast between the two articles "a" and "the". The indefinite NP _a better job_ assumes one's listener does not know what job you're talking about, whereas the definite NP _the better job_ assumes that they do.

Comment: @BillJ That's a consideration as well. I've added it as an introduction.